# how to implement search inside json data with javascript ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have one search box ,in that search json data should append.

here is my html code

```
 <input type="search" id="merchantName" name="merchant" placeholder="enter merchant name"></input>
```

I have json data which contains merchant name. I want to append this merchant name on this search box in list form.how can I do..?this is my js function but here data is not appended in search box.

```
$(responseObj.merchants).each(function() {

    var output = "<ul><li>" + this.merchantName + " " +"</li></ul>";
    $('#list').append(output);

});
```

Comment: What is `#list`??? Please improve your question, posting more of relevant code. What about a jsfiddle? BTW, you should use `$.each()` not `$.fn.each()`

Comment: What type is responseObj.merchants ? Is it an array of json-objects?

Comment: <ul  data-role="listview" id="list" ></ul> and @homungus..yes its the array of json object containing merchant name ,as of now after clicking on search button i m gettint output as .xyz.com and xyz.co.in but i want this output should come only in that search filter box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if responseObj.merchants is an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseObj.merchants.length; i++) {
    var output = "<li>" + responseObj.merchants[i].merchantName + " " +"</li>";
    $('#list').append(output);
}
```

Comment: i m getting output in list form already but i want same should only be appended in that search box..how can i ..?hope u understood..

Comment: you want to append the list of merchant-names to the input-field? the text of the input field should be the list? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This should work or the other approach would be use for loop

```
$.each( responseObj.merchants function(index, value){
    var output = "<ul><li>" + value + " " +"</li></ul>";
    $('#list').append(output);
})
```

Explanation:
For each merchant value we iterate over its value and append it to the output list.

But always, API documentation read is a must.
The page contains examples and explanation to what you need.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/